# Разная работа программы в зависимости от статического/динамического создания контроллов

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу программу WinForms, которая печатает текст с label на pictureBox. Сделал ее двумя способами:

1) Динамически создавая label и pictureBox

2) Статически создавая их же

Основные параметры задал одинаково, однако результаты получились разные. Ниже код первого и второго способов (еще буду кидать `private void InitializeComponent()` из Form1.Designer.cs, чтобы наглядно было видно, что свойства задаются одинаково):

1)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Size = new Size(500, 500);
    var text = "Hello world";
    var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 20);
    var pictureBox = new PictureBox() { Parent = this, BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight, Size = new Size(300, 300), Location = new Point(50, 50) };
    var label = new Label { Parent = pictureBox, Text = text, BackColor = SystemColors.Control, AutoSize = true, Font = font, Location = new Point(60, 60) };

    label.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        label.UseCompatibleTextRendering = !label.UseCompatibleTextRendering;
    };

    pictureBox.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        label.Visible = !label.Visible;
    };

    pictureBox.Paint += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (label.UseCompatibleTextRendering)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label.Text, label.Font, new SolidBrush(label.ForeColor), label.Location);
        else
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, label.Text, label.Font, label.Location, label.ForeColor);
    };
}


private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.Text = "Form1";
}
```

2)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    label.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        label.UseCompatibleTextRendering = !label.UseCompatibleTextRendering;
    };

    pictureBox.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        label.Visible = !label.Visible;
    };

    pictureBox.Paint += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (label.UseCompatibleTextRendering)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label.Text, label.Font, new SolidBrush(label.ForeColor), label.Location);
        else
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, label.Text, label.Font, label.Location, label.ForeColor);
    };
}


private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.pictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    this.label = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // pictureBox
    // 
    this.pictureBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
    this.pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50);
    this.pictureBox.Name = "pictureBox";
    this.pictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
    this.pictureBox.TabIndex = 0;
    this.pictureBox.TabStop = false;
    // 
    // label
    // 
    this.label.AutoSize = true;
    this.label.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
    this.label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 60);
    this.label.Name = "label";
    this.label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(146, 31);
    this.label.TabIndex = 1;
    this.label.Text = "Hello world";
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label);
    this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();
}
```

Вот результаты работ первого и второго способов:

[image: 1-ый способ]

[image: 2-ой способ]

Почему выводы получаются разные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае родительским контейнером для `label` является `pictureBox`. Соответственно, располагается `label` относительно края этого `pictureBox` и закрывает нарисованный текст, который там, скорее всего, присутствует.

Во втором случае родительским контейнером для `label` является `Form1`. Располагается `label` относительно края `Form1`, и вы видите, как нарисованный в `pictureBox` текст, так и `label`, с которого этот текст рисовался.

Comment: Блин, точно, а я что-то подумал, что если `label` в самом начале перенес на `pictureBox`, то он автоматом станет прикрепленным к нему, а не к форме. Сейчас внимательнее посмотрел `InitializeComponent()` и там видно, что `label` добавлен на форму. Спасибо